# Can't output md5 hash as the same one in the database

Tags: php, mysql, hash, md5

I have this little problem that I hope you can solve.

I get this error whenever I try to retrieve the hash from database :
Unknown column '26657d5ff9020d2abefe558796b99584' in 'where clause'

this is my php code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email']) AND isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash'])){

//Verifier les données

    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
    $hash = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['hash']);

    $verification = mysql_query("SELECT email, hash, status FROM utilisateurs WHERE Email = '".$email."' AND
    $hash = '".$hash."' AND status = '0'") or die(mysql_error());
    $match = mysql_num_rows($verification);

    echo $match; // Just for testing how many matches we'll get. We expect "1" or "0"

}else{ 

    //Invalid approach

    echo "Invalid approach, please use the link that has been send to your email.";

}


?>
```

so when I test the url : http://mywebsite.com/verify.php?email=name@gmail.com&hash=26657d5ff9020d2abefe558796b99584 I'm sure the hash exists because I copied it from the database with same email

I get the error :
Unknown column '26657d5ff9020d2abefe558796b99584' in 'where clause'

The hash was made this way : $hash = md5(rand(0,1000));

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query is including the clause:

```
… AND $hash = '".$hash."' AND …
      ^^^^^
```

You want to check the value of the `hash` column, not `$hash`.

Comment: Oh man thank you a lot, sometimes you just focus on hard unexisting stuff instead of just looking at the easiest ones. One more time thank you !